# JQuery append closing tag before data

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I am creating a Adobe Air application with jQuery support. However, the recursive function that I have closes the tag first and writes the data afterwards.

My code is,

```
function displayTodoItems(id)
{
 id = parseInt(id)

 if(!id)
  $("#todoLists").empty();

 var list = fetchTodoItems(id);
 if(list.data == null)
  return;
 var numRecords = list.data.length;  

 for (var i=0;i<numRecords;i++)
 {  
  dateObj = new Date(list.data[i].date_created);

  time = dateObj.getFullYear()+"-"+ String("0"+dateObj.getMonth()).slice(-2)+"-"+ String("0"+dateObj.getDate()).slice(-2)+" "+  String("0"+dateObj.getHours()).slice(-2)+":"+ String("0"+dateObj.getMinutes()).slice(-2);

   $('#todoLists').append('<div id="list'+list.data[i].id+'" class="listitem '+(id?'listitem-sub':'listitem-main')+'" style="background-color: #' + list.data[i].color + ';' +(list.data[i].color/2 < 0x7FFFFF?' color: #FFF;':'')+ '">'+time+ '<br>' + unescape(list.data[i].data)+ '</div>');
  //get child items
  displayTodoItems(list.data[i].id);
  $('#todoLists').append('</div>');

 } 
}
```

The reply I get is,

```
   <div id="todoLists">
  <div id="list1" class="listitem listitem-main" style="background-color: #fff;">2010-07-07 21:01<br>
    Hello Bongo Sister</div>
  <div id="list2" class="listitem listitem-main" style="background-color: #dd9900;">2010-07-07 21:08<br>
    Umer Idiot Thinks that we are using Aptima. Not knowing that we call this Aptana</div>
  <div id="list3" class="listitem listitem-main" style="background-color: #654562; color: #FFF;">2010-07-07 21:42<br>
    asdf asdfa sdfasdf asdf </div>
  <div id="list4" class="listitem listitem-main" style="background-color: #7FFFFF;">2010-07-08 12:40<br>
    Umar is a naughty boy</div>
  <div id="list5" class="listitem listitem-sub" style="background-color: #222; color: #FFF;">2010-07-08 12:46<br>
    Hello Great Boy</div>
  <div id="list6" class="listitem listitem-sub" style="background-color: #000000; color: #FFF;">2010-07-10 20:07<br>
    Farrukh You Idjt</div>
  <div id="list7" class="listitem listitem-main" style="background-color: #FF5500;">2010-07-18 21:45<br>
    Testing new Item</div>
</div>
```

This is wrong, in that list5, list 6 are childs of list 4, so they should be in its div.

I am really struggling. It seems that the jquery is calling append before the recursive function. Is there a way around this.

Kind Regards,

Khuram Javaid

Answer (score 3):

[`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) is used for full elements, you can't add partial strings or just closing tags.  There are many ways to go about fixing this, I'll show a minimal change version here:

```
function displayTodoItems(id, parent)
{
 id = parseInt(id);
 parent = parent || $("#todoLists");

 if(!id) parent.empty();

 var list = fetchTodoItems(id);
 if(list.data == null)
  return;
 var numRecords = list.data.length;  

 for (var i=0;i<numRecords;i++)
 {  
  var dateObj = new Date(list.data[i].date_created),
      time = dateObj.getFullYear()+"-"+ String("0"+dateObj.getMonth()).slice(-2)+"-"+ String("0"+dateObj.getDate()).slice(-2)+" "+  String("0"+dateObj.getHours()).slice(-2)+":"+ String("0"+dateObj.getMinutes()).slice(-2),
      elem = $('<div id="list'+list.data[i].id+'" class="listitem '+(id?'listitem-sub':'listitem-main')+'" style="background-color: #' + list.data[i].color + ';' +(list.data[i].color/2 < 0x7FFFFF?' color: #FFF;':'')+ '">'+time+ '<br>' + unescape(list.data[i].data)+ '</div>')
                .appendTo(parent);         
  displayTodoItems(list.data[i].id, elem);
 } 
}
```

This just passes the element you're creating as the `parent` parameter into the function recursively, since that's what you want to append to, and appends the child elements to *that* instead of  `#todoLists` directly.

Comment: Ok Thanks for that. I'll check this out and get back in this forum. Sounds promising.

Kind Regards,

Khuram

Comment: Thank you Nick. Works like a charm. Learned something new today.

Kind Regards

Comment: Nick, a small request.

I cant seem to change the <div> to <ul>. I want a <ul> to start before the for loop and all elem variables to fill <li> and then end the end the loop with </ul>.
So that, all div structures become nest <ul>.
Would that be difficult?